# $\int_A f dm \leq 0 $ for all $A$ lebesgue measurable implies $f \leq 0 $ a.e

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, elementary-functions

> $$ \textbf{Problem} $$ $\int_A  f dm \leq 0 $ for all $A$ lebesgue
>   measurable set implies $f \leq 0 $ a.e

$$ \textbf{Solution (Attempt)} $$

We want to show $X = \{ x : f > 0 \} $ is a null set, that is $m(X) = 0 $. Consider, $X_n = \{ x : f \geq \frac{1}{n} \} $. We show

$$ X = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n $$

If $x \in X$, then $f > 0 $. By archimidean, can find $n$ such that $f \geq \frac{1}{n}$. therefore, $x \in X_n $ for some $n$. $\therefore$ by definition $x \in \bigcup_n X_n $.

For the reverse direction, if $x \in \bigcup_n X_n $, then $x \in X_n$ for some $n$. Hence, $f \geq \frac{1}{n} > 0 \implies f > 0 \implies x \in X $

Now, we show $m(X_n) = 0$. but by hypothesis,

$$ \int\limits_{X_n} \frac{1}{n} \leq \int\limits_{X_n} f \leq 0 \implies \frac{1}{n} m(X_n) \leq \int\limits_{X_n} f \leq 0 $$

This can only happen if $m(X_n) = 0$ Which implies by additivity of the measure that $m(X) = 0$. Therefore, $f \leq 0 $ a.e.

Is this correct?

Comment: Almost. The property you use is not additivity but $\sigma$-additivity, since you have infinitely many $X_n$. And at some point, the premise that $f$ be measurable should be mentioned, I think.

Comment: you are very formal Daniel

Comment: Sometimes. Better to be overly pedantic when turning in homework than getting points deducted for being imprecise, isn't it?

Comment: i have strong opinions on math formality. But thanks for your opinion.

Comment: There are a few English mistakes you might consider fixing. Also, it's bad form to use the triple dots instead of writing out 'therefore'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $E = [f > 0]$. This is measurable.  Since $f >0$ on $E$, 
$$\int_Ef(x)\,dx \ge 0.$$ 
but by your hypothesis, this integral cannot be positive, so 
$$\int_E f(x)\,dx = 0$$
Necessarily, $f = 0$ a.e. on $E$, so $|E| = 0$.  Since $[f>0]$ has measure zero, $f \le 0$ a.e.

Comment: Could someone help me understand why $f=0$ a.e in $E$. implies $m(E)=0$?